# DataView rows - order by most recently modified?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dataset, dataview

What we're doing - we have some DataGrids bound to some DataViews and when the user hits a 'submit' button we want to pass all the changed rows to a SPROC. There are some complexities here I can't go into detail about but...

what we need - a list of the modified rows ordered by the time they were modified. Is this possible? I doubt it is possible with the current DataView class so I was wondering what other options I have?

Using .NET 4.0

Kind regards,
Fugu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to manually add a column "ModifiedTime" that will hold the modified date and time. Every time a row is modified, modify the "ModifiedTime" column by updating its value to current date and time. Now you can simply sort by "ModifiedTime" to get required results.